# Value from select option is returning NULL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to insert a record into the database using an id from a dropdown. I am then trying to pass it to my model and save the record, however it says that the hero_id is null, even though the request should pick up the hero_id from the value of the dropdown.

My view:

```
<form method='POST' action='/profile/addPlay'>            
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{old('title') }}" name="title" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label for="video">Video</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{old('video') }}" name="video" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label for="hero_id">Hero</label>
                <select name="hero_id" class="form-control" id="hero_id">
                    @foreach ($hero as $heroes)
                        <option value="{{$heroes->id}}">{{$heroes->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Add your play
            </button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
    @if(count($errors))
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

My controller:

```
public function insertPlayProfile (Request $request,Hero $hero){

    $this->validate(
        $request,[
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'video' => 'required'
        ]
    );

    $play = new Plays($request->all());


    $hero->addPlayOnProfile($play, Auth::user()->id);

    return back();
}
```

My model:

```
public function addPlayOnProfile(Plays $play, $userId){
        $play->user_id = $userId;
        return $this->plays()->save($play);
    }
```

I have also made the user_id fillable in my Plays model.

I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: plays.hero_id (SQL: insert into "plays" ("title", "video", "user_id", "hero_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (thghfghgf, ghgfdhfg, 1, , 2017-01-22 21:23:56, 2017-01-22 21:23:56))

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you already checked whether or not the select box truly contains the id's as value (use chrome devtools) ?? If it does, what does the `$request` and/or `$play` variables contain? Do they contain the `hero_id`? Guess it's a good thing to check them first ;)

Comment: As @ErikvandeVen mentioned, check the page source (CTRL+U in chrome or firefox) to see if the values are populated correctly.

Comment: Yes, they do have the correct ids, the options seem to be correctly populated @R.Mazarei

Comment: @ErikvandeVen They do, when I do a var_dump on the play variable, the request doesn't pick up the value at all **object(App\Plays)#210 (23) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "title" [1]=> string(5) "video" [2]=> string(7) "user_id" }**

Comment: Alright. Forgive me if I'm talking bullshit, cause I'm quite new to Laravel, so ;) But how does `/profile/addPlay` look like? And perhaps there is some function in your router which doesn't send every variable to the controller? The best way to find the issue, is to track down each step by step. With such incomplete image of your code, it isn't easy for us to find the issue either ;)

Comment: @ErikvandeVen im not passing any variables through my controller, i dont know if I'm supposed too **Route::post('profile/addPlay', 'ProfileController@insertPlayProfile')->middleware('auth');**